# Truffle migrate - TypeError: migrations.setCompleted is not a function

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, ganache, truffle-migration

I ran `$ npx truffle migrate` to deploy 2 contracts to Ganache but I got an error:

```
This version of µWS is not compatible with your Node.js build:

Error: Cannot find module './uws_darwin_x64_88.node'
Falling back to a NodeJS implementation; performance may be degraded.



Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)


1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
   > transaction hash:    0x4aace13bc13ed0956004c7bf4af40a052797d620d69bb95d412bec36271366e9
   > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
   > contract address:    0x76167b6D1E41AFEb8F55c36316D1DB0C1BD6BCba
   > block number:        1
   > block timestamp:     1665666248
   > account:             0xD7D15925b6b7760e27edA967700D2df22CaEad55
   > balance:             99.99865868
   > gas used:            67066 (0x105fa)
   > gas price:           20 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.00134132 ETH


Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.


**TypeError: migrations.setCompleted is not a function**
    at Migration._deploy (/Users/AAHD/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:98:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at Migration._load (/Users/AAHD/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:54:1)
    at Migration.run (/Users/AAHD/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:202:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/Users/AAHD/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:142:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/Users/AAHD/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:107:1)
    at Object.run (/Users/AAHD/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:91:1)
    at module.exports (/Users/AAHD/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/runMigrations.js:10:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/Users/AAHD/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/run.js:41:1)
    at runCommand (/Users/AAHD/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command-utils.js:201:1)
Truffle v5.6.0 (core: 5.6.0)
Node v15.14.0
```

Here is the code in 1_initial_migration.js

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

I'm learning and it's the first time I'm deploying so I'm not sure how to fix the error.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in contracts directory, you should have `Migrations.sol` and its code should be like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner = msg.sender;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    require(
      msg.sender == owner,
      "This function is restricted to the contract's owner"
    );
    _;
  }
  // this might not be set correctly
  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }
}
```

Comment: @aahd_fr plain thanks does not work here: you should accept it to thank :)

Comment: Sorry, just done it :)